Pdfl-lib Genexus error "Unmatched save level" when adding an image
So, i'm currently using GeneXus 7.5 and Pdf-Lib  6.4 (I know it's outdated) trying to create a pdf report, but whenever I try to add an image, the application stops with the runtime error "Unmatched save level". I know this has been fixed in later versions, but is there some way of solving the error? for example with editing the generated VB code myself?
I am 99% sure it was working a couple days ago so I don't really know if something changed or if I had solved it in the past and somehow it got lost.
